# Will Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate work on my Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

Good Morning,

Currently I am enrolled in a software development course at a small college, and as a student, I have a DreamSpark account and access to all the software therein.

However for much of the last decade I have used strictly Mac's at home, and what I would like to know is if I installed Windows on one of my Mac's, would I be able to install and run Visual Studio Ultimate that we use for school?

The source of this concern is what my classmates and instructor say, what Apple users say, and what I would like to do. My classmates and my instructor all viscerally hate Apple products, whereas I don't like Windows but am willing to use it if a job requires it. The folks at the Apple store, of course, believe that I would have no issues running VS or other such software on my main Mac at home.

What I would like to know is if my main home computer has the capacity to run VS and whatever else I need to work as a software developer if I install Windows on it as opposed to selling it and buying a new PC.

At home my main Mac is a custom-built 24" iMac with 3.06GHZ, 8GB of RAM, and 1TB hard drive. If I installed Windows on this Mac, could I install and run VS, SQL, etc.?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes; If it runs Windows it can run Windows software such as you mention.

Comment: plenty of my students have run windows nicely on macs.. oddly it seems to be a very happy sweat spot between hardware and software.